# Core i7 860 8MB vs. core i7 860 overclock

Tags: computer-building

I plan to buy this computer on black friday: [Velocity Micro z30](http://www.velocitymicro.com/wizard.php?iid=186). I want to buy a core i7 860 but I'm not sure if i want to overclock version or the one with 8MB of cache. I plan to use it for gaming, programming, watching HD, using 3 monitors with high resolutions and a bit of graphic and video editing.

Should i pick the i7 860 w/ 8MB cache or overclock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That CPU has 8MB cache, overclocking does not affect this and they must of forgotten to write the 8MB.

Personally, I wouldn't overclock a modern CPU, they are fast enough and it is asking for trouble, but if they are offering it overclocked, they will obviously support it so, if it is the same price, go for it!